# Python- how to query database by class

Tags: python, django, get, class-instance-variables

I have a Python project (I'm quite new to Python), and on one of the webpages, there is a drop-down box which should display a list of all of the projects whose 'status' fields are set to 'live'.

It seems that a couple of particular objects are not being displayed in this drop-down box, so I want to manually query the database to check what their 'status' fields are set to.

How do I manually query the database for these particular projects by their 'project name'/ 'project code', both of which I know are unique?

I've tried getting a list of all of the projects in the shell, so that I can query that list by `project_name` for the particular projects that I want using the commands:

```
from projects.models import Project
prjcts = []
prjcts = Project.objects.all()
```

This gets all of the `Project` objects and assigns them to the list `prjcts`. I now want to query that list for a particular project, and have tried doing so like this:

```
6Stoke = prjcts.get(project_code = 6SPR)
```

My intention was that the project with the `project_code` whose value was `6SPR` would be assigned to the variable `6Stoke`, so that I could then find look at all of the information for that particular project. However, when I tried running this line in the console, I got a

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

warning which highlighted the end of the `6Stoke` part of the line.

What is wrong with my syntax here? How can I get the project that has the specified `project_code` and assign it to a variable?

**Edit**

Ah, ok- thanks. I changed the variable name, and ran the query again, assigning its results to the variable `sixStokeList`, i.e.

```
sixStokeList = Project.objects.filter(project_code = "6SPR")
```

- this returned two items, and having printed the elements of the array to the console, i.e. `sixStokeList[0]` & `sixStokeList[1]`, I know which one I want, so I've assigned that particular one to a variable with:

  sixStoke = sixStokeList[1]

I have then typed `sixStoke.` and pressed 'tab' in the console to see what's available to this variable. I did the same with another project, i.e.

```
theFoss = Project.objects.filter(project_code= "1TF")
theFoss. (& pressed 'tab')
```

The list of available options given after typing `variable` + `.` + `tab` was different for each `project` instance, even though I had got them both in exactly the same way, which would indicate to me that they are not instances of the same class... how can this be, given that I got them both by querying the same class?

Comment: It's just that variables cannot start with digits in python

Comment: You can't name a variable beginning with a number. Call it `SixStoke`, or `Prj6Stoke`, or `Stoke6` or something.

Comment: the 6SPR (project code) is an string? maybe you should use like this :

`6Stoke = prjcts.get(project_code = '6SPR')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't name a variable beginning with a number

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks very much. I removed the number, and was able to assign class instances to the variables. I assigned a couple of instances to different variables using the same `filter()` method, just passing in a different value for the `project_code` that I was filtering on... but it seems that the instances of the two variables belong to different classes given the options that are available to them are different- how could this be given that I got them both by querying the same class? I've updated my question to include this detail...